# Django REST Framework, only Admin can DELETE or PUT

Tags: python, django, rest, django-rest-framework

I'd like to ask how I can control object permissions within Django Rest Framework with the effect that:

- `User` has no ability to `DELETE` nor `PUT`
- `Admin` is a `User` that also can `DELETE` and `PUT`
- In order access API / `SAFE_METHODS` `User` must be `Authenticated`

I have tried standard permissions, such as `permissions.IsAdminUser` and `IsAuthenticatedOrReadOnly`, but no match.

Is there a standard Permission to achieve below? If not, what is the best next step, to control permissions via Django models or via DRF?

```
| API end-points        | HTTP Method   | Authenticate  | Permissions  | Result                                       |
|---------------------- |-------------  |------------   |------------  |------------------------------------------    |
| /products             | GET           | User          | User         | List of product                              |
| /products             | POST          | User          | User         | Create new product                           |
| /products/{product_pk}| GET           | User          | User         | Retrieve details of particular product       |
| /products/{product_pk}| PUT           | Admin         | Admin        | Fully update particular product's info       |
| /products/{product_pk}| PATCH         | User          | User         | Partially update particular product's info   |
| /products/{product_pk}| DELETE        | Admin         | Admin        | Delete particular product's details from DB  |
```

Serializers.py

```
class ProductSerializer(HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
class ProductView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    authentication_classes = [authentication.SessionAuthentication, authentication.TokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAdminUser,)
```

urls.py

```
router_v1 = routers.DefaultRouter()
router_v1.register('products', ProductView)

urlpatterns = [
    path('v1/', include(router_v1.urls)),
    path('api-token-auth/', views.obtain_auth_token, name='api-token-auth'),
    path('api-auth/', include('rest_framework.urls'))
]
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Override the **`get_permissions(...)`** method as

```
class ProductView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = Product.objects.all()
    serializer_class = ProductSerializer
    authentication_classes = [authentication.SessionAuthentication,
                              authentication.TokenAuthentication]
    permission_classes = (permissions.IsAdminUser,)

    def get_permissions(self):
        if self.request.method in ['PUT', 'DELETE']:
            return [permissions.IsAdminUser()]
        return [permissions.IsAuthenticated()]
```